# Getting error Polymer::Attributes: couldn`t decode Array as JSON

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, polymer

I'm trying to pass an array from a PHP script to a source of a custom element, this is the setup.

In the PHP I get the data from a MySQL database and fill the array 
with PHP:

```
        $rows = array();

        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $rows[] = $r;
        }
```

Here I have a custom component (a list) that a source type Array, like so:

```
 Polymer ({
                is: 'list-view',
                properties: {
                    arraySource:
```

I'm trying to pass the value with a json encode command:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./list-view.html">
</head>

<body>
    <dom-module id="main-view">
        <template>
            <div>
                <list-view id="list" array-source='<?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>' as="item"></list-view>
            </div>
        </template>

        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: 'main-view'
            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>
</body>

</html>
```

If I put a simple JSON manually like `array-source='[{ "user" : "foo" }, { "user" : "bar" }]'` it works fine, but when I use the method as above this error pops up in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Sample from debugging:

```
<list-view id="list" array-source='[{"user":"name1"},{"user":"name2"},{"user":"name3"} ... etc etc...
```

I thought it didn't like some extra quotes that the PHP function echo is adding somehow, but I'm not seeing anything while debugging.

Comment: try to copy the json string from your php output and check it using a [json linter](http://jsonlint.com/) to see if there is any issue in the json

Comment: It says it's a valid JSON

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: If I debug the thing, copy the json, in the html instead of <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>,  it works. WHY?

Comment: Polymer::Attributes: couldn`t decode Array as JSON

Comment: the error is in polymer-micro.hmtl line 673 if it can help...